# Variables are not behaving as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, delayedvariableexpansion

I've been wrestling trying to get the syntax right on this batch file and I cannot figure out why some things aren't working.

1. The variable `i` is not getting incremented each time I do it.
2. Concatenation on `strc` doesn't seem to concatenate.

Here is my code:

```
set i=0
set "strc=concat:"

for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set "str=intermediate%i%.ts"

    set strc="%strc% %str%|"

    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "%str%"
)

set strc="%strc:-1%"
ffmpeg -i "%strc%" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc Output.mp4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable inside a loop for /F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805187/how-to-set-a-variable-inside-a-loop-for-f)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are not the first, who fell into the famous "delayed expansion trap" (and you won't be the last).

You need delayed expansion if you want to use a variable, that you changed in the same block (a block is a series of commands within parentheses `(`and `)`).

Delayed variables are referenced with `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

Reason is the way, `cmd` parses the code. A complete line or block is parsed at once, replacing normal variables with their value at parse time. Delayed variables are evaluated at runtime.

Two simple batch files to demonstrate:

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=hello"
if 1==1 (
    set "var=world"
    echo %var% !var!
)
```

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    echo %random% !random!
)
```

*Note*: A line is also treated as a block:

```bat
set "var=old"
set "var=new" & echo %var%
```

With delayed expansion:

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=old"
set "var=new" & echo !var!
```

Delayed expansion is per default turned off at the command prompt. If you really need it, you can do:

```bat
cmd /V:ON /C "set "var=hello" & echo !var!"
```

Also there is a way to do the same without delayed expansion (but `call` costs some time, so it's slower, but if for some reason you can't / don't want to use delayed expansion, it's an alternative):

```bat
setlocal DISabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1 1 5) do (
    call echo %random% %%random%% 
)
```

Both methods can also be used to display [array-like variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990):

(This is often asked like "variable which contains another variable" or "nested variables")

Here is a collection for using such array-like variables in different situations:

**With delayed expansion:**

```bat
setlocal ENableDelayedExpansion
set "num=4"
set "var[%num%]=HELLO"
echo plain delayed: !var[%num%]!
for /L %%i in (4 1 4) do (
    echo for delayed: !var[%%i]!
    set a=%%i
    call echo for delayed with variable: %%var[!a!]%%
)
```

**without delayed expansion:**

```bat
setlocal DISableDelayedExpansion
set "num=4"
set "var[%num%]=HELLO"
call echo plain called: %%var[%num%]%%
for /L %%i in (4 1 4) do (
    call echo FOR called: %%var[%%i]%%
    set a=%%i
    call echo FOR called with variable: %%var[%a%]%%
)
```

**Note**: `setlocal` has no effect outside of batchfiles, so `delayedexpansion` works only:

- In batch files
- When the cmd was started with delayed expansion enabled (`cmd /V:ON`) (by default, the cmd runs with delayed expansion **dis**abled)

(Follow the links, when you are interested in the [technical background](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) or even the [advanced technical stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/2152082))